# Embedding php file

Tags: php, jquery

In my index.php I use jQuery's .load() to change the content of a div. That content is stored in a php-file that uses ARRAYS from the index.php. So when I load the php into my div, it does not have access to those arrays. Do I need to make them global or is there an other way to fix this?

I kind of want the page to be reinitialized with that new php content embedded into the index.php, so it acts like one file. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP's `include()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Just use $_GET variables on your .load() url

```
$('#result').load('request.php?var1=<?=$value1?>&var2=<?=$value2?>');
```

and on the request.php file:

$variable1 = $_GET['var1'];
$variable2 = $_GET['var2'];

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that we are actually talking about pretty long arrays here.

Comment: Then use POST variables. `load`s second parameter `data` should be for that.

Comment: So please show part of your code, cannot help you without it.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you are trying to use PHP variables in your index.php AFTER it has already been sent to the browser.

what you are trying to do is not possible since these variables do not exist on the client side since PHP is server side only.

what you can do is send these variables through to the jquery.load() in the URL like:

```
$.load('url.php?var1=value1&var2=value2');
```

but you will need to initialise them before hand in your index.php file, so in your index.php file you will have a line like this:

```
<?php echo "$.load('url.php?var1={$value1}&var2={$value2}');"; ?>
```

not sure what oyu are trying to accomplish but this might work for you.